# Can razor dynamically display form inputs based on user selection?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

When a user selects a option 3 within the dropdown menu below:

```
<div class="col-md-5">
  <select class="form-control valid" id="MeterTypeEntry_RceTypeId" name="MeterTypeEntry.RceTypeId">
    <option selected="selected" value="0">IMT</option>
    <option value="1">MIT</option>
    <option value="2">CMT</option>
    <option value="3">ALM</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

I would like to use Razor to display only the first dropdown list shown below:

```
<div class="col-md-5">
  @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.MeterTypeEntry.MeterConversionType.Key, Model.AltimusTypesList, new{@class="form-control"})
  @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.MeterTypeEntry.MeterConversionType.Key, Model.MitMeterTypeList, new {@class = "form-control"})
  @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.MeterTypeEntry.MeterConversionType.Key, Model.CmtTypesList, new {@class = "form-control"})
</div>
```

I was hoping to do this within the same form and display only the `AltimusTypesList` dropdown without having to submit the `#MeterTypeEntry_RceTypeId` but trigger it on the selection of the value 3 option.

I realize this can be done very easily in jQuery and that it is the best solution for this type of problem, but I am interested in knowing if there is a solution that can be done only in Razor.

Comment: No.  Razor gets translated into HTML on the server side before being sent to the requesting client.  You will need Javascript to do this.

Comment: You'll have to use some javascript at some point with what you want to do, this is just fact! The only way you can trigger something when you change a dropdown is to use JS of some description, even if you did some sort of POST you'd have to use JS to trigger the form sumbit..... wow posted comments at same time!!

Comment: Thanks Coda17 and matt_lethargic. That is what I suspected. I appreciate the help!